# Java scanner no error appears

Tags: java

I'm writing one of my first java codes and I can't get it to run. When I run the code it tells me there are errors but in the console at the bottom nothing appears for me to see what the error might be. Please help?

```
package operators;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment2ifelse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quantity;
    int packages = 99;
    quantity = input.nextInt();
    double dis1 = .2; // dis2 = .33, dis3 = .42, dis4 = .29;
    double price = packages * quantity;
    double discount = 0;
    double finalprice = price * discount;

    if (quantity < 20 && quantity > 9) {
      System.out.println(price);
      discount = price * dis1;
      System.out.println(discount);
      System.out.println(finalprice);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what the errors are.

Comment: No errors appear that's why I'm lost.

Comment: You said in your question that "when you run the code it tells me there are errors." What does it tell you?

Comment: input is underlined orange and says its never closed?

Comment: At the very end of your main method, call `input.close()`

Comment: That warning has nothing to do with why you aren't seeing anything though. YassinHH's answer explains it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
package operators;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment2ifelse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quantity;
    int packages = 99;
    System.out.println("Enter a quantity : ");
    quantity = input.nextInt();
    double dis1 = .2; // dis2 = .33, dis3 = .42, dis4 = .29;
    double price = packages * quantity;
    double discount = 0;
    double finalprice = price * discount;

    if (quantity < 20 && quantity > 9) {
      System.out.println(price);
      discount = price * dis1;
      System.out.println(discount);
      System.out.println(finalprice);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Quantity doesn't match expectations.");
    }
  }
}
```

Actually, the program runs but it doesn't show you anything because it begins immediately by waiting for an input from the user:

```
quantity = input.nextInt();
```

Then, it shows you something only if your entry matches the condition of your if test.

Next time, try to create an interaction with the user by prompting them with messages using `System.out.print()`.

Comment: When I run that i get this after I terminate the code:

  Exception in thread "main"

Comment: Try it now, I forgot a bracket :)

Comment: Thank you ! (: but the input still says the input is never closed?

Comment: The Scanner object stops running once the main Thread has stopped so you do not have to worry about it. But you may close it manually at the end of your code.